# Removing a column with table editor components

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a table that includes several columns with check boxes in them. Occasionally, my code needs to remove the columns and create new ones. When I do this via the following code

```
int columnscount = myTable.getColumnCount();

//remove the columns
for(int i=2;i<columnscount;i++){
    myTable.getColumn(2).dispose();
}
```

All the columns are removed but the checkboxes are not. How do I remove the editor components? They are created using this code

```
TableEditor editor = new TableEditor (myTable);
editor.minimumWidth = checkButton.getSize().x;
editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
editor.setEditor(checkButton, ti, colCheckCount);
```

Comment: Time for a SSCCE.. A small program self sufficient program that has showcases the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of removing a column from Swing's `JTable` is by invoking `removeColumn` method:

`table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));`

Be cautious however, because this only removes the column from view without removing the underlying data.

Comment: The other way would be to simply tell the TableModel to remove (i.e. not return that column)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to change the way I did it. Instead of deleting my columns, I just disposed of the entire table and recreated it. Works great.